# How do I access Material-ui's theme in Styled Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm using CRA with Material-ui and Styled Components type of styling.
When building my CSS I want to access Material-ui's default theme.

part of package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.2.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.2.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2"
  }
```

When I try the below `theme` exists on `props` but is an empty object.

StyledApp.js:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export const StyledButtonUsingTheme = styled(Button)`
  //Below will give "Cannot read property 'error' of undefined" 
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.palette.error.light};
`;
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

import { StylesProvider, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import { StyledButtonUsingTheme } from "./StyledApp";

function App() {
  const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme();

  window.console.log("Default theme passing to ThemeProvider", defaultTheme);

  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
        <div className="App">
          <StyledButtonUsingTheme variant="outlined">
            Styled Button Using Theme
          </StyledButtonUsingTheme>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The console.log in `App.js` shows the whole theme object, and that's what I pass to ThemesProvider. Interestingly `props.theme` is there! but sadly with no values.

Comment: I have a workaround: 
Inside StyledApp.js to use: background-color: ${props => createMuiTheme().palette.error.light};
...but it feels like a hack to call createMuiTheme() each time I want to use the theme

Comment: But you are no passing the `theme` to `StyledButtonUsingTheme` in any way. I don't see how this can work

Comment: I'm expecting theme to be added to every child component of <ThemeProvider>. It is actually added but empty. Note that theme is not undefined, it is an empty object, where did it come from?

Comment: Watch out: you are importing `styled` from the wrong place. `import { styled } from '@material-ui/styles';`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-kapitsa-l3bn3 copied and pasted example from https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#themeprovider.

Comment: @keul if I do that then no styling is working. Forget the theme, no styling is respected at all. But you have a point and this got me thinking in the right direction. I obviously mixed up stuff / libraries.

Comment: @Eric Menezes, for your example to work you need to use <StylesProvider injectFirst> just as I do in App.js. Else no styling in the StyledButtonUsingTheme.js file is respected, we get a default Material-ui button. Thanks a bunch, now that I see something that works I get new hope and energy

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As Horyd in the comment says, using the `ThemeProvider` from `Styled-Components` will give you access to the theme properties inside your styled component. 
But Material-UI doesn't apply that theme anymore to its own components.

The workaround I found is as ugly as it is simple: **Use both Themeproviders**. So Material-UI applies the theme to its components and you can access the theme in your styled components.

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { MuiThemeProvider,StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

ReactDOM.render(

  //Make sure the Material stylesheet is placed above your own 
  //styles so you can overwrite them
  <StylesProvider injectFirst> 

    //Use the theme in the ThemeProvider for Material-UI so
    //styles are applied to the Material-UI components
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>

      //Use also the ThemeProvider for Styled-Components so 
      //you can access the theme in your own css
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>

        //Include your app and you have acces to everything 
        <App />

      </ThemeProvider>

    </MuiThemeProvider>

  </StylesProvider>,

document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: for MUI v5 use `ThemeProvider` instead of `MuiThemeProvider` and `StyledEngineProvider` instead of `StylesProvider `

Answer (score 22):

You could use ***withTheme*** :

App.js

```
import React from "react"
import { ThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import { StyledButton } from "./StyledButton"

const App = () => {

    const theme = createMuiTheme();

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <StyledButton />
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}

export default App
```

StyledButton.js

```
import { styled, withTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button"

export const StyledButton= styled(withTheme(Button))(props => ({
  background: props.theme.palette.background.paper,
}))
```

Answer (score 7):

Problem Solved!

The solution is to use:
`import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";` in App.js then the `theme` is there with all the values on the `props` object.

I used ThemeProvider from "@material-ui/styles" in App.js
`import { StylesProvider, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";`
That doesn't play well with `import styled from "styled-components" in StyledApp.js

The working two files:

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

import { StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import { StyledButtonUsingTheme } from "./StyledApp";

function App() {
  const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme();

  window.console.log("Default theme passing to ThemeProvider", defaultTheme);

  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
        <div className="App">
          <StyledButtonUsingTheme variant="outlined">
            Styled Button Using Theme
          </StyledButtonUsingTheme>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

StyledApp.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export const StyledButtonUsingTheme = styled(Button)`
  //Below will work now!
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.palette.error.light};
`;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this actually solves the issue of simultaneously providing the theme to styled-components constructed using `styled` and also automatically applying the theme to material-ui components such as `<Button color="primary">Click me</Button>`. Using your solution the second example does not adhere to the theme

Answer (score 7):

The answer which used withTheme is almost complete. The last part didn't work for me, so I changed to:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { withTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles"

const StyledButton = withTheme(styled('h1')`
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.palette.error.light};
  `
)
```

Answer (score 5):

I did it in MUI v5 like this

```
import { styled as muiStyled } from '@mui/material';

const NavLinkStyle = muiStyled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: '0 10px',
  height: '100%',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  '&:hover': {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    borderRadius: '15px'
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use both ThemeProviders, first from styled-components and second from material-ui, you can use **alias** for one of them:

```
import { ThemeProvider as StyledThemeProvider} from 'styled-components';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

 function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <StyledThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Wrapper>
          <TheHeader />
          <TheContent />
          <TheFooter />
        </Wrapper>
      </StyledThemeProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Router >
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

For MUI v5:

`index.tsx`

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { StyledEngineProvider} from "@mui/material";
import { ThemeProvider as ScThemeProvider } from "styled-components";

import App from "components/App/App";

const theme = createTheme();

ReactDOM.render(
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <ScThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <App />
      </ScThemeProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </StyledEngineProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I found that the `theme` object is automatically passed in with the [`styled` component](https://mui.com/system/styled/#using-the-theme) and can be accessed via parameter as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@material-ui/core';

const StyledButton = styled('button')(({ theme }) => ({
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));
```

I have this working in MUI v4.11.0.

Comment: Thank you! This saved my butt since I have a ton of styled components and didn't want to implement `withTheme` all over the place

Answer (score 0):

in your styled component you can use the hooks useTheme example :

```
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core"
import { styled } from "@material-ui/styles"

const theme = useTheme

  const StyledListbox = styled("ul")({
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

While many of the answers here tell you to use multiple theme providers, that is unnecessary with MUI5 as there is a special version of their styled engine that you can install to replace the default emotion based one.

If you use that, there is also no need to wrap your styled components within `useTheme` or similar features. You can just "magically" access the theme by accessing the props:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Example = styled.span`
background-color: ${props => props.theme.palette.primary.main};
`
```

If you get errors about undefined theme vars even after installing `@mui/styled-engine-sc`, you might need to update your bundler configuration.

The [official docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/styled-components/) have info for webpack and next.js as well as a config snippet you need if you're using typescript.

If you're using vite, you need to add the following to your `vite.config.[j|t]s`:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '@mui/styled-engine': '@mui/styled-engine-sc',
    },
},
```